# included files php do not appear in a browser

Tags: php, html

I have a php page(**index.php**) that includes another html file(**footer.html**). Am using dreamweaver, and my problem is: The included file(footer.html) shows in the main file (**index.php**) in dreamweaver design view, but does not show in the browser preview. I have both the php files in the root directory, so they're at the same level. I have tried using `require` rather than `include` with the same result. My `include` code is:

```
<?php include("footer.html");?>
```

does anyone see something wrong off the bat?

Comment: Your include language is...?

Comment: <?php include("footer.html");?>

Comment: What OS are you working on, what about file permissions?

Comment: @ManuelGutierrez Take a look at the tags before asking such question.

Comment: am using window 7 32-bit.. can u tell about file permission please

Comment: nope it was wrong, removed the comment. The way to do it would be more like `readfile("footer.html");`

Comment: don't care about file permission, i don't think this is the source of your problem, so are you sure that your file name is footer.html and not footer.php ? we need also to know about your code where you include this part (footer), please add more details

Comment: The issue isn't related to PHP by the sound of it... well it is - but just the fact that you probably aren't running it through the interpreter in your "browser preview" - try deploying to a server for test.

Comment: Look at the raw source code in the browser. I'll bet you'll see your `<?php ?>` unprocessed as is in there. Have you set up a web server properly?

Comment: Site is running only on my own machine so far, using xammp from Apache, but both Apache and MySql are running. Thank you.

Comment: @maro but when you hit "browser preview" (that sounds like some garbage dreamweaver button?) does the URL read `http://localhost/my-project/index.php` or does it look more like `file://some/path/indended/for/static/preview.html` - because if it's simply loading the file from your file system it won't work.

Comment: The url reads:file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/coictstudent/index.php

Comment: Well that's the root of your problem, assuming `/htdocs` is your webroot and your server is running you should be using a url similar to: `http://localhost/coictstudent/index.php`

Answer (score 0):

**Do realy exist file "footer.html"?**
If no create them.

**Is file "footer.html" in the same directory as "index.php"?**
If no add it to the same directory.

**Do you have any content in your "footer.html" file?**
If no add any and check if it appears on page.